# Redirecting using htaccess based on referrer

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect all the requests from a referrer folder. Here is the scenario.

I want all the requests with referrer from  http://www.example.com/demo/ex1/*.* to http://www.example.com/ex1/*.*

Help Please.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have that many subpages that you can't do this:

```
# Redirect old file path to new file path
Redirect /olddirectory/oldfile.html http://mt-example.com/newdirectory/newfile.html
```

or is for some specific reason?

if so, you can play a little with this and obtain your answer ;)

```
# To redirect all users to access the site WITHOUT the www. prefix,
# (http://www.example.com/... will be redirected to http://example.com/...)
# adapt and uncomment the following:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mt-example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mt-example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Just in case you are asking this is for the .htaccess

Comment: But this thing has nothing to do with REFER rite? HTTP_REFERER or some thing ?